# How to handle multiple requests in socket io in node in single page and handle that specific event

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I have 2 websites one for sending events of payment transaction alert, and another website receive those events if it is handling with one page to one page it's perfectly working, but if I send one alert from one tab to the receiver and another alert from another tab to that same receiver, I want to confirm the alert that received in receiver website, according to their alert emitted page.. How do i do that... Using socket.io in node

Need solution for this